# Why isn't "private_key.pepk" file not used to generate app signing key in the new version of Google Play Console website anymore?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

When I created an **app bundle** in Android Studio, a ***"private_key.pepk"*** file was generated along side the **app bundle**. In an old tutorial of publishing an **app bundle** in the Google Play Console I have noticed ***"private_key.pepk"*** file was required to upload for generating the **app signing key**.

This is the first time I am publishing an app bundle. Besides, I am publishing it in the new web version of the Google Play Console. I just uploaded my **app bundle** and uploading ***"private_key.pepk"*** file was not required to generate the **app singing key**.

Does it mean we do not need the ***"private_key.pepk"*** file anymore or I just made a mistake while publishing my app bundle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to enroll in Play Signing in the Play Console.

If you're publishing a **new** app:

1. By default, Play Console will generate the private key when you upload your first APK/AAB
2. There is an advanced option before uploading the first APK/AAB which allows you to choose which key you want to sign the APKs that Play will sign with. When opting for this option, Google gives you a set of commands to run using the PEPK tool.

If you're enrolling in App Signing **after** having published at least one APK/AAB:

3. You need to transfer the private key to Google. The Play Console gives the set of commands to run using the PEPK tool, but as a convenience, Studio has already run the commands for you and already provides you the encrypted key to upload: the file `private_key.pepk`.

You are likely in case #1, in which case the key used to sign your APK/AAB was used as an *upload key* and will be used by Play to ensure that the artifact was not modified between you generating it and it reaching Google servers. All your future uploads will need to be signed with the same key.

And thus the file `private_key.pepk` is of no use for you.

Comment: I think the advanced option of case #2 is no longer available in the new web version of Google Play Console. So, case #1 is the only way to go and **private_key.pepk** is not needed anymore.

Comment: Yes, option #2 it's still available: https://imgur.com/a/MMN4c8A

Comment: Oh! But think case #2 will be hardly used by someone.

Comment: @Pierre i have pepk file, debug.keystore file and password, 
how to update existing android app with new one (lost jks)??

Comment: If you're enrolled in Play Signing, then follow the instructions here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#reset 
You should be able to initiate the reset in the Play Console in the "Setup > App integrity" page.